# How to create a video from my app in browser (Chrome)?

Tags: javascript, html, video-capture

How to create a video file from animations that run in a div (or other DOM element) in Javascript. For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes example {
  0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
  25%  {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
  50%  {background-color:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
  75%  {background-color:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
  100% {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

So, I want this animation to be saved in a file like .avi or .mp4, ... I did a lot of research and I didn't get a satisfactory solution. Just something like html2canvas() that seems to be just for print. PS: in Javascript (with any library, plugin?)